# How to Get only checkedBox rows from gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some gridView with checkBox option, I want to get only CheckedRows and make a new GridView with them.
GridView:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewMediaAndSource" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMedia" 
         CssClass="mGrid"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
        PageSize="15" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="MediaType" HeaderText="Източник" />
              <asp:BoundField  DataField="mediaName" HeaderText="Име на медията" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

How to make new GridView with only data which was cheked from this view

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided your code so, I hope this give you a start.

```
    for(int i=0; i< Grid.Rows.Count(); i++)
    {
          CheckBox check = (CheckBox)Grid.Rows[i]["CheckColumnName"].Controls[0];
          if(check.Checked)
          {
              //do something
                 }
    }
```